# Pandas - how to create a new dataframe from the columns and values of an old dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file in which I have tweets with the following column names: File, User, Date 1, month, day, Tweet, Permalink, Retweet count, Likes count, Tweet value, Language, Location.

I want to create a new data frame with tweets from certain cities. I can do it but only for the last city on my list (Girona). So it doesn't add all the rows. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path_to_file = "populismo_merge.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, encoding='utf-8', sep=',')

values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("A Coruña",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Alava",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Albacete",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Alicante",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Almería",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Asturias",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Avila",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Badajoz",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Barcelona",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Burgos",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Cáceres",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Cádiz",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Cantabria",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Castellón",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Ceuta",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Ciudad Real",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Córdoba",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Cuenca",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Formentera",na=False)]
values = df[df['Location'].str.contains("Girona",na=False)]
values.to_csv(r'populismo_ciudad.csv', index = False)
```

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Please post sample input dataframe with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path_to_file = "populismo_merge.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, encoding='utf-8', sep=',')

cities = ['A Coruña', 'Alava', 'Albacete', 'Alicante', 'Almería', 
          'Asturias', 'Avila', 'Badajoz', 'Barcelona', 'Burgos', 
          'Cáceres', 'Cádiz', 'Cantabria', 'Castellón', 'Ceuta', 
          'Ciudad Real', 'Córdoba', 'Cuenca', 'Formentera', 'Girona']

values = df[df['Location'].isin(cities)]
values.to_csv(r'populismo_ciudad.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: thank you very much, it was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `values` variable each time. A more concise answer would be along the lines of.

```
values= df[df['LocationName'].isin(["A Coruña", "Alava", ......)]
```